# What is MonadBaseControl for?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm digging deeper into Yesod's monads, and have encountered `MonadBaseControl`.
I took a look at the hackage doc, and got lost. Could someone tell me the problem it is trying to solve?

Comment: It's actually from [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control), the package description there says "This package defines the type class MonadBaseControl, a subset of MonadBase into which generic control operations such as catch can be lifted from IO or any other base monad." Doesn't tell me which problem it's meant to solve, unfortunately.

Comment: Take a look at [lifted-base](hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base). It provides lifted versions of many standard `IO`-based functions. For example, using `MonadBaseControl` you can write a piece of code that runs inside a complex `IO`-based monad stack, and call [`fork`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.2.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Lifted.html#v:fork) inside that stack, transferring whatever context the monad has into the forked thread as well.

Comment: A colleague has written a really nice intro and walkthrough: https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/09/07/demystifying-monadbasecontrol/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It comes from the package [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control), and is one of a pair of type classes (the other one being [MonadTransControl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-control/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t%3aMonadTransControl)) that enhance [MonadBase](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers-base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Base.html#t%3aMonadBase%20%22transformers-base%3aControl.Monad.Base%3aMonadBase) (resp. [MonadTrans](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t%3aMonadTrans)) by supporting an alternative `liftBase` (resp. `lift`) operation for monads that implement it.  This enhanced version no longer takes a simple action in the absolute base monad (resp. immediate base monad), but instead takes a function that *gets the base monad's (resp. monad transformer's) whole state at that point* as its only parameter and returns the aforementioned action.

As the package documentation states, this enhancement, along with the rest of the contents of these type classes, allow you to lift functions like `catch`, `alloca`, and `forkIO` from the absolute base monad (resp. immediate base monad), which is not possible with the simpler scheme present in [MonadBase](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers-base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Base.html#t%3aMonadBase%20%22transformers-base%3aControl.Monad.Base%3aMonadBase) (resp. [MonadTrans](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t%3aMonadTrans)) because the latter pair do not allow you to lift the *arguments* of a function, just the *results*, while the approach taken by [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control) allows both.

As a result, the set of monads (resp. monad transformers) that can be used with [MonadBaseControl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-control/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t%3aMonadBaseControl) (resp. [MonadTransControl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-control/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t%3aMonadTransControl)) is a strict subset of the set of monads that can be used with [MonadBase](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers-base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Base.html#t%3aMonadBase%20%22transformers-base%3aControl.Monad.Base%3aMonadBase) (resp. [MonadTrans](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t%3aMonadTrans)), but the former groups are much more powerful than the latter for the same reason.

Answer (score 20):

Michael Snoyman actually wrote a small tutorial on monad-control: http://www.yesodweb.com/book/monad-control

The gist of that article might be the following:

Imagine you have this piece of code:

```
withMyFile :: (Handle -> IO a) -> IO a
withMyFile = withFile "test.txt" WriteMode
```

You can apply `withMyFile` to any function of the type `Handle -> IO a` and get a nice `IO a` value. However, what if you have a function of the type `Handle -> ErrorT MyError IO a` and want to get a value of type `ErrorT MyError IO a`? Well, basically, you will have to modify `withMyFile` in order to incorporate a lot of wrapping/unwrapping. MonadBaseControl allows you to somewhat 'lift' functions like `withMyFile` to certain monad transfromers which allows unwrapping ("running"). Thus, resulting code looks like this:

```
useMyFileError :: (Handle -> ErrorT MyError IO ()) -> ErrorT MyError IO ()
useMyFileError func = control $ \run -> withMyFile $ run . func
```