# Lift a function and its argument to a different monadic context

Tags: haskell, monads

I am not sure how to formulate this question scientifically exact, so I am just going to show you an example.

I am using state in a `StateT` transformer. Underlying is `IO`. Inside the `StateT IO` operation I need to use `alloca`. However, I can't lift `alloca` to `StateT IO` because it expects an argument of type `(Ptr a -> IO a)` while I require it to work with an argument of `(Ptr a -> StateT IO MyState a)`.

(However, this is a generic question about monad transformers rather than specific to `IO`, `StateT` or `alloca`.)

I came up with the following, working solution:

```
-- for reference
-- alloca :: (Storable a) => (Ptr a -> IO b) -> IO b

allocaS :: (Storable a) => (Ptr a -> StateT s IO b) -> StateT s IO b
allocaS f = do
  state <- get
  (res, st) <- liftIO $ alloca $ \ptr -> (runStateT (f ptr) state)
  put st
  return res
```

However, it seems wrong to me that I should have to de- and reconstruct the `StateT` action in order to use it with `alloca`. Also, I have seen this pattern in some variations more than once and it's not always as simple and safe as here with `StateT`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think the type of `alloca` is not general enough to allow what you want to do. It takes a function returning `IO` instead of a function returning any monad in which IO can be lifted (i.e., a `MonadIO`). In this specific case you can avoid the unpacking if you implement `allocaS` using `malloc/free` instead of `alloca` (if you do, watch out for exceptions). In the general case, I can not see any way to do it without having a more general form of `alloca`. Perhaps you can write such a general `alloca` first by going quite low-level and using GHC primitives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished using [`MonadBaseControl`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-0.3.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl) in [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control), which has been devised exactly for this purpose:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import qualified Foreign.Ptr as F
import qualified Foreign.Marshal.Alloc as F
import qualified Foreign.Storable as F

alloca :: (MonadBaseControl IO m, F.Storable a) => (F.Ptr a -> m b) -> m b 
alloca f = control $ \runInIO -> F.alloca (runInIO . f)
```

This enhanced version of `alloca` can be used with any monad stack based on `IO` that implements `MonadBaseControl`, including `StateT s IO`.

Instances of `MonadBaseControl` allow their monadic values to be encoded in the base monad (here `IO`), passed to a function in the base monad (like `F.alloca`) and then reconstruct them back.

See also [What is MonadBaseControl for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11694299/1333025)

Package [lifted-base](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base) contains many of the standard `IO` functions lifted to `MonadBaseControl IO`, but `alloca` isn't (yet) among them.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon,

AFAIK, there is no general way to turn a function of type `(a -> m b) -> m b` into `(a -> t m b) -> t m b` because that would imply the existence of a function of type `MonadTrans t => (a -> t m b) -> (a -> m b)`.

Such a function cannot possibly exist, since most transformers cannot be stripped so easily from a type signature (how do you turn a `MaybeT m a` into an `m a` for all `a` ?). Hence, the most general way to turn `(a -> m b) -> m b` to `(a -> t m b) -> t m b` is `undefined`.

In the case of `StateT s m`, there is a loophole that allows you to define it anyway. Since `StateT s m a === s -> m (s,a)`, we can rewrite the type equation to :

```
(a -> StateT s m b) -> StateT s m b
=== (a -> s -> m (s,b)) -> s -> m (s,b)
=== s -> (s -> (a -> m (s,b)) -> m (s,b) -- we reorder curried arguments
=== s -> (s -> (A -> m B)) -> m B -- where A = a, B = (s,b)
```

Solving this new type signature is now trivial :

```
liftedState f s run = f (run s)
allocaS :: Storable a => (Ptr a -> StateT IO b) -> StateT IO b
allocaS = isomorphic (liftedState alloca)
```

That is about the best we can do in terms of code reuse, short of defining a new subclass of MonadTrans for all monads that exhibit the same behaviour.

I hope I made myself clear enough (I didn't want to go into too much detail for fear of being confusing)

Have an excellent day :-)

Comment: Interesting answer too, +1 and thanks for your work. What is `isomorphic`?

Comment: `isomorphic` is a sufficiently-smart (and fictional) function that knows how to convert between all isomorphic types. In practice, we can use Lenses to achieve the desired effect (in this case, `isomorphic` would be `view (flipped.bimapping (flipped.wrapping StateT) (wrapping StateT))`)

Comment: Since we have already proved the isomorphism between the types of `liftedState alloca` and `allocaS`, all that `isomorphic` does is characterize that isomorphism and apply it with `view`. ERRATA: `flipped.wrapping StateT` should be `flipped.mapping (wrapping StateT)`