# Lift a function with a monad parameter into a monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I want to lift a function like [`mask_ :: IO a -> IO a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:mask_) to create a function with this signature: `lmask_ :: StateT Bool IO a -> StateT IO a`.

My problem is, how to handle the callback/first parameter? Wouldn't the following code be incorrect since it would execute the callback before `mask_`'s code?

```
lmask_ :: StateT Bool IO a -> StateT Bool IO a
lmask_ m = do
  r <- m
  lift (mask_ (return r))
```

Is there some general way to do this? A helper like `lift1 :: MonadTrans t => (m a -> m a) -> (t m a -> t m a)`?

Answer (score 2):

If we generalize `lmask_` to get rid of the `StateT Bool IO`, we get something like this:

```
lift1 :: (Monad m, Monad (t m), MonadTrans t) => (m a -> m a) -> (t m a -> t m a)
lift1 f term = do
    x <- term
    lift (f (return x))
```

Answer (score 2):

In general this is not possible without knowing something about the monad transformer. However, there is a way how to do this for all the standard monad transformers. See type class [`MonadBaseControl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-control-1.0.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Control.html#t:MonadBaseControl). It's superclass `MonadBase` defines what is the bottom monad in a monad transformer stack (which is `IO` for all stacks that include `IO`), and `MonadBaseControl` defines a way how to embed the monad into the base monad. Its instances are somewhat convoluted, but once they're defined, it's possible to lift all such functions like `mask_`.

In your case, package *lifted-base* uses the above construction to re-define the standard `IO` functions lifted to `MonadBaseControl`. In particular, there is [`mask_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.3.6/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v:mask_)

```
mask_ :: MonadBaseControl IO m => m a -> m a
```

which can be specialized to `StateT Bool IO a -> StateT Bool IO a`, as `StateT s` has an instance of `MonadBaseControl`.

See also [Lift a function and its argument to a different monadic context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25102588/1333025).